# Background image over background image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to a background image over background image but it hides the first one image . My code is as follows

```
<li class="collapsed">
<a>Getting Started</a>
</li>


.collapsed {
background-image: url(../images/expand_new1.png)!important;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 141px 5px;
background-size: 35px;
-moz-background-size: 30%;
-webkit-background-size: 30%;
z-index:50;

li.collapsed  a{

opacity: 0.8;
background-image: url(../images/assets/faq/faq_list_bg.png);
display:block;
padding-left:27%;
font-family:  'Roboto';
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 300;
color: #fff;
z-index:-1;
```

I want to display **expand_new1.png** display top of **faq_list_bg.png**

please help to resolve this issue.

expand_new1.png image is white and faq_list_bg.png image is blue . it totally hide the first image.

[![When i replace the plus icon with white color plus icon then image disappears][1]][1]

Comment: Why have the background image at all?

Comment: this is a list and expand_new1.png image is dynamically change with javascript

Comment: when i add other color image then it shows with faded but for white its completely invisible.

Comment: can you upload a demo for better understanding please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
background-image: url(../images/assets/faq/faq_list_bg.png);
```

EDIT BASED ON NEW INFO:

```
li.collapsed  a:after {
background-image: url('../images/expand_new1.png');
background-size: 20px 20px;
display: inline-block;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
content: "";
}
```

http://puu.sh/pBTSS/ffc491e491.png

If you want to change the + to a - or nothing all together once expanded:

```
li.collapsed.expanded  a:after {
background-image: url('NEW IMAGE LINK HERE');
background-size: 20px 20px;
display: inline-block;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
content: "";
}
```

Comment: You said: I want to display expand_new1.png display top of faq_list_bg.png,  you need to clarify what that means. The way describes sounds you want to see expand_new1.png only. and have faq_list_bg.png hidden behind.  Jfiddle setup goes a long way.

Comment: I want to display white plus icon with getting started . see in the link http://melpapp.com/beta/userguide.html

Comment: So you want getting started [+]?

Comment: @VipinS you may want to do a :before sudoclass -- remove the absolute positioning and 11% margin.  Instead add  margin-right: 20px; -- this way it doesn't grow super huge space as it expands.

Answer (score 0):

It hides the first image because you used the `z-index` property but didn't set the `position` value.

`z-index` is not working because it will only work on an element whose `position` property has been explicitly set to `absolute`, `fixed`, or `relative`.

In your case, set `position` for both to `absolute`.

Comment: what u want to do?  display 1st image over the second image or 2nd image below 1st imge ?

Comment: one more thing u didn't add display:block in first image !!

Comment: if u want to image over image set position:"absolute" and if u want image below other image set position:"relative"

Comment: it's not working i have added position absolute and z-index . see the link http://melpapp.com/beta/userguide.html

Comment: sorry, i didn't notice that you are using **z-index**  in class **li.collapsed** and also in **li.collapsed a" but **z-index** property effects container as well as it's child so as per your code if you will change z-index of **li.collapsed" then also it will effect **li.collapsed a**  so what you can do is make a blank dive container with **class="img"** ans set that container **position-absolute** ,**z-index-10** ,**background-image-url(your image path)** and there u go!! :)

Comment: @ jay remove the screen shot